# Stretched raster legend badly displayed ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, symbology, legend

I have a stretched raster in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 with this symbology:

[image]

But when I put the layer in the legend, it's showed like this:

[image]

I've tried to change the styles, showing and hiding headers, changing size, text-size, etc. But it always seems broken. I've deleted the layer and put it again and nothing changes, I even have created the layer again.

What's going on?

Is not the first time I have this issue. Sometimes doing one of the mentioned things was solved, other times nothing worked.

Comment: As a test have you tried any other colour ramp to see if this odd legend behaviour exists?

Comment: Yes I have, but it's not a colour problem